# How do I return void from private int?

Tags: java, void

So I'm taking a Java class and I don't understand this. I've been googling, but this problem is so specific that I just don't know anymore. so here's some of the code

```
private int keychainReturn (int keychainCount, int keychainPrice)
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("You have " + keychainCount + ".");
    System.out.println("Keychains cost " + keychainPrice + " each.");
    int totalprice = (keychainPrice * keychainCount);
    System.out.println("Total cost is $" + totalprice + ".");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Now all that is fine, but I need a return statement. The problem states that I must return void type.

Here's how I'm "summoning the private int":

```
if (choice == 3)
{
    keychainCount = keychainReturn(keychainCount, keychainPrice);
}
```

Don't worry about the if statement and choice, they work fine. Now I can't change much about this due to the nature of the assignment, but here's the exact way the objective is written.

`viewOrder()` will need to be passed two ints, and have a return type of void. It will display, on three different lines, the number of keychains in the order, the price per keychain, and the total cost of the order.

(ViewOrder is just the name of the 3rd option).

Comment: `keychainReturn` is not `viewOrder`... Are you showing the correct method?

Comment: So what exactly is stopping you from making the return type `void` and removing the assignment to `keychainCount`?

Comment: @David nothing, I just didn't know you could do that, as I said I'm still learning, but now that I did that, it worked! :)

Answer (score 2):

If it needs to be a void return type, then the method must say `private void`

Since it has no return type, you just call the method, not assign to anything

```
if (choice == 3) {
    keychainReturn(keychainCount, keychainPrice);
}
```

Comment: Yeah this worked like a charm! Thanks! I don't know how I didn't think of that.